# Evaluate $\int \ \frac{2}{{}x\sqrt{9x^2 - 25}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate

$$\int  \  \frac{2}{{}x\sqrt{9x^2 - 25}} dx$$

So I know that if I had just $$\int  \  \frac{2}{{}x\sqrt{9x^2 - 25}} dx$$ then I would be able to use a natural log rule $\frac1a \text{arcsec}\left|\frac xa\right|+ c$
Am I able to pull out the $2$ from the integral? It would look like

$$2 \int  \  \frac{1}{{}x\sqrt{9x^2 - 25}} dx$$

Furthermore, I have two $x$ values here $1$ and $9$, so would I have to further simplify in order to just have one $x$ value?

I could ALSO just do $\dfrac{2}{(x)(3x-5)}$ but does this make finding the integral harder or easier?

Just new at this guys and would love some clarification.

Comment: You should try using latex while asking questions (and posting answers)! It helps others to help you(and you to help others).

Comment: The $2$ is irrelevant, it can be pulled out. If your function is $\frac{2}{x\sqrt{9x^2-25}}$, the proposed simplification s not right. But there are a couple of standard methods for calculating the integral. I will not do it, since I am not really sure what your function is.

Comment: I mean...I'm looking for some help so any answers would be greatly appreciated. The formula you posted was correct. @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One standard way is to let $3x=5\sec \theta$. Then $3\,dx=5\tan\theta\sec\theta$. And then a miracle occurs. Our integral becomes
$$\int \frac{6}{5\sec\theta\tan\theta}\cdot       \frac{5}{3}\tan\theta\sec\theta\,d\theta,$$
Almost everything cancels.  The integral is $2\theta+C$, and $\theta=\text{arcsec}(3x/5)$.

Another way is to rewrite our integrand as $\dfrac{2x}{x^2\sqrt{9x^2-25}}$. Now let $9x^2-25=u^2$. Then $9x\,dx=u\,du$ and $x^2=\dfrac{25+u^2}{9}$. So we end up with
$$\int \frac{9}{(25+u^2)u}\cdot \frac{2u}{9}\,du.$$
Note the cancellation. The integral that remains is straightforward.

Comment: The beginning stumps me, how did you get that 3x

Comment: Let us do the substitution another longer way. We have $\sqrt{9x^2-25}=5\sqrt{\frac{9x^2}{25}-1}$. We want to use the identity $\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$ to get rid of the square root. So we want $\frac{9x^2}{25}=\sec^2\theta$, meaning that we will let $\sec\theta=\frac{3x}{5}$. That's the substitution I used.

Comment: Hey I'm just curious, could I also use partial fraction decomp?

Comment: Offhand, I can't think of a way to end up needing partial fractions.  If we do a rationalizing substitution like above, the rational function we end up with is, because of cancellation, too simple to require partial fractions.